# Spring mvc does not support encoding utf-8 in output console

Tags: java, spring

I have project in intellij Spring MVC
when I want to print data on output console the none english chars does not support.
In Spring controller method

can somebody help me what is issues

Comment: Many things can be wrong here. Basically make sure you use the same character encoding everywhere (Java, OS, terminal, ...)

Comment: Please show us the code you are using

Comment: I use windows 10 64 bit english version

Comment: Intellij IDEA  I set encoding file to utf-8 also project setting to utf-8 I tried to use main method in my Controller class output was right

Comment: Inside web xml I put filter but it is not help

Comment: Also I put encoding for tomcat server and -Dfile.encoding for JAVA_OPTS